# @ConfigurationProperties - unexpected behavior in case of missing / unresolved properties

Tags: spring-boot

I'm working on an application based on spring boot 2.4.3.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "keystore")
@ConstructorBinding
@Validated
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class KeyStoreProperties {
    @NotBlank(message = "keystore password should be provided")
    private final String password;
    @NotBlank(message = "keystore path should be provided")
    private final String path;
}
```

```
@Service
public class KeyStoreService {

    private final KeyStoreProperties properties;
    private KeyStore keyStore;

    public KeyStoreService(KeyStoreProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
}
...
```

application.properties

```
keystore.password=${KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}
keystore.path=keystore/keystore.p12
```

I expect that if the `KEY_STORE_PASSWORD` env. variable is not set, the KeyStoreProperties.password will be resolved to null. But it has a value `'${KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}'`.

According to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10463 is should be a feature, but in my oppinion it causes an unexpected behavior. That makes troubles in my running system because the password for the keystore is set to the wrong value. I would like to have a failure on the application startup, like "unresolved property ...". How can I reach that? A better solution in my oppinion would be to make this configurable by introducing an extra attribute like @ConfigurationProperties(ignoreUnresolvable=false).

Answer (score 1):

As Spring sees that as a feature you could add a Regex validation to both properties:

```
public class KeyStoreProperties {

    @Pattern(regexp="\${\S*}", message="unresolved property")  
    @NotBlank(message = "keystore password should be provided")
    private final String password;

    @Pattern(regexp="\${\S*}", message="unresolved property")  
    @NotBlank(message = "keystore path should be provided")
    private final String path;
}
```